# Using new <%: %> syntax/Razor with Mono & ASP.NET MVC`

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mono, razor

Mono 2.8 claims to have C# 4.0/ASP.NET MVC 2 support.

However the new `<%: %>` syntax doesn't work.

Neither does Razor.

Is there  a way to make them work or should I just wait for Mono 3?

Comment: Razor is in MVC 3, not MVC 2, so yeah.. that won't work.  The <%: %> nuggets are part of ASP.NET 4.0, not C# 4.0.  I don't know whether or not Mono supports ASP.NET 4.0 or not fully.

Comment: Razor was released as an add-on to MVC2.  MVC3 is the first version where it comes with the MVC library.

Comment: So, there's no way to use Razor at the moment, right? Or is there an add-on I can install?

Comment: Brian is not correct in the sense that Razor was never released as an add-on to Mvc2. It's always been in the form of a Mvc3 prerelease. While it might be possible to get Razor working for Mvc2 (and only on .Net4), it would not be an approach endorsed by Microsoft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Mono 2.8 [release notes](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.8) seems to indicate [ASP.NET 4.0](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.8#ASP.NET_4.0) is now supported. It also points out that the `<%: %>` syntax works (listed as `Html Encoded Code Expressions`).

However, as pointed out by Mystere Man, Razor is MVC3. MVC3 has not yet been released, so it's not prudent to expect this in Mono for some time.

A quick search of the Mono forums [suggests](http://go-mono.com/forums/#nabble-td3037880%7Ca3037918) that MVC3 doesn't yet play with Mono 2.8.

Answer (score 1):

bin deployment of MVC3 is working using mono master [see post by mono devs about mvc3](http://twistedcode.net/blog/post/2011/01/17/Mono-and-ASPNET-MVC-v3.aspx) but there are still many exception as only System.Web.Mvc is open source other component sourceless

Answer (score 0):

Out of box support isn't there yet due to Razor itself not being part of the open source MVC assembly, but I have Razor working on Mono 2.8.1 by setting up precompilation and a custom view engine / base class that does not call BuildManager.

http://tqcblog.com/2011/01/23/precompiled-razor-for-shared-views-and-mono/